# Given a discrete distribution,how to plot cdf?

Tags: r

Give a discrete distribution `X = [2,1,5]` with weight `W = [0.5,0.2,0.3]`.How to plot cdf of this distribution in r?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
xx <- sort(x)
WW <- cumsum(W[order(x)])
plot(xx,WW,type="s",col = 2, xlab = "x",ylab = "p(x)")
points(xx,WW,col = 4)
```